# customize user modification form django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

When you create/modify a user from the django admin site you have this interface :

[image: permissions form from the user interface dajngo admin]

My project is quit simple because I have no group and every staff user could have superusers satus. That is why I want not to show the superuser status option, neither groups and user permissions. How to mask this sections of this form and assert that all staff users also superusers are.

This form is generated here : django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html

and especially at this lines :

```
{% block field_sets %}
{% for fieldset in adminform %}
  {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

So I need to modify the adminform variable but in don't know how.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do. In your `admin.py` file define a new user admin like that with the fieldsets you want :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _

# Register your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )


# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

# don't show groups
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify that template. so you Have a look at

django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/auth/user/

This should contain a couple of templates for modifying the users.

You can override these by copying them to TEMPLATE_DIR/admin/auth and then changing them.

Also, look @ django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html

This is the file you'd copy and change (to TEMPLATE_DIR/admin/auth/user/) to override the change form for that model.

Comment: thanks for your help. I edited my question with your helps, but changing the html isn't the solution, because you can only show or hide everything about the user.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your requirement/question, You want to remove the permission box.

If that is the case you must remove the PermissionsMixin class from your CustomUserModel just keep AbstractUser/AbstractBaseUser.

for example now your custom user model looks like this:

```
class CustomUserModel(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # your code...
```

Instead do this:

```
class CustomUserMode(AbstractUser):
    # your code...
```

Delete the exising db to see the changes.